# Get child DirectoryInfo directory of parent DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, directory, io

I have following path:

`G:\C#\Dump.WebApi\src\Dump.WebApi`

```cs
string currentDirectory = GetCurrentDirectory();
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = GetParent(currentDirectory)!.Parent!;
```

The result of this code is:
`G:\C#\Dump.WebApi`

Now i want to go to `bin` folder. But i cant find according method.

`G:\C#\Dump.WebApi\bin`

What I only can its get list of subdirectories:

```cs
directoryInfo.GetDirectories();
```

What can I only do is:

```cs
directoryInfo.GetDirectories().Single(directoryInfo => directoryInfo.Name == "bin");
```

Is there simple method for this? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Although `EnumerateDirectories` might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeking a concise approach, you can do this:

```
directoryInfo.CreateSubdirectory("bin");
```

Even if the bin directory already exists, this method will not have error. Of course, there will be some overhead as it will attempt to create a new directory. A more efficient approach is still to use `Path.Combine`:

```
new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, "bin"));
```